# Limit 1 after filter in django

Tags: python, django

```
SystemsV2.objects.filter(Q(sysname = 'DC_BW_SBX_S4H') | Q(sysname='DC_BW_DEV_S4H')).values('sysname')
```

Executing the above command gives this output,

```
<QuerySet [{'sysname': 'DC_BW_SBX_S4H'}, {'sysname': 'DC_BW_SBX_S4H'}, {'sysname': 'DC_BW_DEV_S4H'}]>
```

How can we make it so that only one of each exists in the result. For example,

```
<QuerySet [{'sysname': 'DC_BW_SBX_S4H'}, {'sysname': 'DC_BW_DEV_S4H'}]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.distinct()`

```
SystemsV2.objects.filter(Q(sysname = 'DC_BW_SBX_S4H') | Q(sysname='DC_BW_DEV_S4H')).values('sysname')\
    .order_by('sysname').distinct()
```

Comment: So using distinct is like editing the query set that we already got?
Cant we actually send a query to the db instead of filtering the queryset using django?

Comment: It is NOT editing the query after fetching it from db. It uses `SELECT DISTINCT` in its SQL query, and it is the database that filters the query and guarantees the uniqueness.